# Android Share Button Last Tweaks

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Hello all i have a button i am trying to let users share a specific sentance that has been created by three wheels that i have in my app this is the code i have so far:

```
 private void mixWheel(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.scroll(-25 + (int) (Math.random() * 50), 2000);

    private String getWheelValue(int id) {
        WheelView wheel = getWheel(R.id.passw_1);
        int index = wheel.getCurrentItem();
        ((ArrayWheelAdapter<String>) wheel.getViewAdapter()).getItemText(index).toString();
        String values = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_1) + " " + getWheelValue(R.id.passw_2) + " " + getWheelValue(R.id.passw_3);
        return values;

        Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tweet);
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.Subject));
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.Message));
                startActivity(emailIntent);

            }
        });
```

The problem is after "wheel.scroll(-25 + (int) (Math.random() * 50), 2000);"

I get this error "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody"

If i put it after that line of code i then get an error under
"Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tweet);"

Saying: Unreachable code
With qucik fix "Remove" but this just removes everything after that line of code i have posted the full code below just incase. Thanks in advance.

```
    public class PasswActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.passw_layout);
initWheel(R.id.passw_1, new String[] { "You", "Me", "Us" });
initWheel(R.id.passw_2, new String[] { "Are", "Going", ""Went });
initWheel(R.id.passw_3, new String[] { "There", "Here", ""Away });




    Button mix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mix);
    mix.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_1);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_2);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_3);

        }
    });

}

// Wheel scrolled flag
private boolean wheelScrolled = false;

// Wheel scrolled listener
OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener() {
    public void onScrollingStarted(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = true;
    }

    public void onScrollingFinished(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = false;

    }
};

// Wheel changed listener
private OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if (!wheelScrolled) {

        }
    }
};

/**
 * Initializes wheel
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the wheel widget Id
 */
private void initWheel(int id, String[] values) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.setViewAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this, values));
    wheel.setCurrentItem((int) (Math.random() * 10));
    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    wheel.setCyclic(true);
    wheel.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());

}

/**
 * Returns wheel by Id
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the wheel Id
 * @return the wheel with passed Id
 */
private WheelView getWheel(int id) {
    return (WheelView) findViewById(id);

}



/**
 * Tests entered PIN
 * 
 * @param v1
 * @param v2
 * @param v3
 * @param v4
 * @return true
 */
private boolean testPin(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4) {
    return testWheelValue(R.id.passw_1, v1)
            && testWheelValue(R.id.passw_2, v2)
            && testWheelValue(R.id.passw_3, v3);

}

/**
 * Tests wheel value
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the wheel Id
 * @param value
 *            the value to test
 * @return true if wheel value is equal to passed value
 */
private boolean testWheelValue(int id, int value) {
    return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem() == value;
}



/**
 * Mixes wheel
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the wheel id
 */
private void mixWheel(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.scroll(-25 + (int) (Math.random() * 50), 2000);

    private String getWheelValue(int id) {
        WheelView wheel = getWheel(R.id.passw_1);
        int index = wheel.getCurrentItem();
        ((ArrayWheelAdapter<String>) wheel.getViewAdapter()).getItemText(index).toString();
        String values = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_1) + " " + getWheelValue(R.id.passw_2) + " " + getWheelValue(R.id.passw_3);
        return values;

        Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tweet);
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.Subject));
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.Message));
                startActivity(emailIntent);

            }
        });


 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your getWheelValue() method inside of mixWheel? Try moving it outside of mixWheel like so, and re-organize your calls

```
private void mixWheel(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.scroll(-25 + (int) (Math.random() * 50), 2000);




 }

private String getWheelValue(int id) {
        WheelView wheel = getWheel(R.id.passw_1);
        int index = wheel.getCurrentItem();
        ((ArrayWheelAdapter<String>) wheel.getViewAdapter()).getItemText(index).toString();
        String values = getWheelValue(R.id.passw_1) + " " + getWheelValue(R.id.passw_2) + " " + getWheelValue(R.id.passw_3);
        return values;

        Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tweet);
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.Subject));
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.Message));
            startActivity(emailIntent);

        }
    });

}
```

I'm not even sure if that is valid syntax (a method within a method) - someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the code but i still get an error message under "Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tweet);" saying unreacable code

Comment: Hi Jack, i ahve to add a closing  } at the end which then gives the error i stated above?

Comment: @Matt You are calling `return values` in the middle of getWheelValue, before you call Button share = ... - How can anything else be called after you return values? Also your getWheelValue() method is calling itself, which is recursion. One of the key things about recursion is that you must have a conditional to STOP the recursion. I don't see how your method even works.

Comment: Yes i have copied the code you posted exactly but i have to add a closing } right at the end or i get an error at the end, but when i add the closing } i get the other error

Comment: Could you help me out on correcting the code then if thats ok? Thanks in advance